# Error with inserting data into BigQuery table

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I try to insert data from pandas dataframe into GBQ table and got an "invalid data error". GBQ table has following schema:

| Field name | Type | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | STRING | REQUIRED |
| order_id | STRING | REQUIRED |
| action_date | DATE | NULLABLE |
| product_name | STRING | NULLABLE |
| order_sum | FLOAT | NULLABLE |
| website_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| website_name | STRING | NULLABLE |
| webmaster_id | STRING | NULLABLE |
| webmaster | STRING | NULLABLE |

and dataFrame has such structure:

| id | order_id | action_date | product_name | order_sum | website_id | website_name | webmaster_id | webmaster_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 830339411 | 970561 | 2022-02-25 | product_1 | 1000.0 | 123 | site 1 | 456 | webmaster 1 |
| 830339412 | 970562 | 2022-02-25 | product_2 | 1500.0 | 120 | site 2 | 456 | webmaster 1 |

and dtypes:

| column | type |
| --- | --- |
| id | object |
| order_id | object |
| action_date | object |
| product_name | object |
| order_sum | float64 |
| website_id | object |
| website_name | object |
| webmaster_id | object |
| webmaster | object |

originally `action_date` column had a format like `2022-02-25T20:31:02` but I have transformed it to `2022-02-25` with

```
all_orders['action_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['action_time'])
all_orders['action_date'] = all_orders['action_time'].dt.date
```

so when I try to insert some rows to GBQ I get an error:

```
'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'action_date', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': "Invalid date: '1644019200000'"}]
```

It looks like GBQ consider a date in action_date column as unix timestamp. How to fix it?

Comment: Hi! yep, thanks a lot! You`re my saviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse the `2022-02-25T20:31:02` format before write, use the following and write to the table.

```py
dataframe['action_time'] = pandas.to_datetime(dataframe['action_time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Here is an full functional example on writing dates to BigQuery:

```py
import datetime
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas
import pytz

client = bigquery.Client()

table_id = "<project>.<ds>.<table>"

records = [
    {
        "date": '2022-12-25T20:31:02',
        "data": "Final Teste",
    },
]
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
    records,
    columns=[
        "date",
        "data",
    ],
)


dataframe['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(dataframe['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("date", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.DATE),
        bigquery.SchemaField("data", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
    ],)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(dataframe, table_id) 
job.result()  

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print("Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id))
```

**result on table:**
[image]